# Android : How to control progressbar (which is in action bar of acivity) from other fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have created `NavigationDrawer` app. On each item there is a `WebView`.
I have added `ProgessBar` in `ActionBar` using following code.

```
      requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
```

My problem is I want to show `ProgressBar` (in `ActionBar`) when page from Fragment starts loading and hide ProgressBar(in `ActionBar`) when page loading is finished.

Below is my code snippet how I created `ProgressBar` from main `Activity`

```
   //....other code
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
//....Other code
```

Here is my `Fragment` contents

```
public class HelpFragment extends Fragment {
WebView web;
View rootView;  
public HelpFragment() {
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_help, container, false);              
    web = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview01);

    web.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    return rootView;
}
public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient
{
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);            
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);        
    }
   }    
}
```

Please suggest the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `Activity` instance from it's fragments by calling `getActivity()`
So to show/hide progressbar in the `Activity`'s Actionbar, you can use code like this:

```
getActivity().setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(/*true or false here*/);
```

Comment: Another Issue raised that when i go back or select another fragment then application unexpectdly stops

Comment: @VaibhavrajRohamRaJ create new question and post the stacktrace there